# How do I print user input to a file in Perl?

Tags: perl

I want to save user's input to a file and each time the enter key is pressed, the user input must be printed and written to the file.

```
$name = <STDIN>;
chomp $name;

while { open File,">", "filename.txt" or die$!;

    open( MYFILE, '>>filename.txt' );
    print MYFILE $name;
    close(MYFILE);
    close File;

    chop($_ = <>);
    eval($_);
    warn() if $@;
} while ($_ ne "exit")
```

Comment: Would you like to use jquery?

Comment: @BhavinSolanki What has this to do with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**repeat_after_me.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $outfile = 'output.txt';

print "Please type stuff:\n";
open(my $output, ">>", $outfile)
    or die "Unable to open $outfile for append : $!";
while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    last if m|^exit$|;
    print "You typed '$_'\n";
    print $output $_ . "\n";
}
close $output
    or die "Unable to close output.txt : $!";
```

**perl repeat_after_me.pl**

```
Please type stuff:
hello
You typed 'hello'
goodbye
You typed 'goodbye'
exit
```

**cat output.txt**

```
hello
goodbye
```

Comment: Can I suggest this would be better with a 3 arg `open`. Also - given you insert `\n` each time, the `chomp;` would seem to be redundant.

Comment: Finally, it's better practice (much more flexible) not to hardcode names of input and'or output files into scripts, and supply them as arguments instead, or even better, just write to standard outut and redirect it to a file in the call to your script.

Comment: Updated to use 3 arg open.  chomp is there so I can print out the input string between quotes.  I agree with not hard-coding filenames, but this is just an example script, it can (of course) be improved.